# SMART showing bad block but ECC recovered is 0 without erase failure on a Samsung 870 EVO SSD

Tags: ssd, smart

Have a question about SMART attributes of an SSD drive. Namely Samsung 870 EVO, the deal is that there are 6 bad blocks and 6 blocks used from the reserve, also 6 reallocated sectors.

But ECC recovered is 0. There's also no erase failure reported. So the question is...

1. Is the drive re-reading the written data just after the write  and then it reallocates the block after the controller detects that the data isn't matching what is supposed to be written? So that's a write error and no data is lost?
2. Or is the drive checking the content of the block *before* erase, and then if ECC isn't matching (so the block is damaged) - the block is moved? So basically the drive is loosing data for some blocks but as these blocks are discarded and never read from it seems to be working "correctly" and i'm just lucky

````
5   Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
9   Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       11806
12  Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       55
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   094   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       131
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   057   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       43
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       506391182296```
````

Comment: "*But ECC recovered is 0. There's also no erase failure reported.*" -- You seem to misunderstand what `Hardware_ECC_Recovered` represents, and then make wild speculations.  See https://kb.acronis.com/content/9131 and https://superuser.com/questions/1511864/smart-value-for-ecc-recovery-is-both-increasing-and-decreasing-what-does-this

Comment: This acronis page you linked is a generic description of an attribute for a generic HDD, not even a generic SSD. And the description is totally irrelevant because H_E_C never increase linearly with time for any samsung SSD. 

As for Samsung it actually states that H_E_C is "Count of correctable errors. Number of errors corrected by internal error correcting mechanism", so not even sure what some random HDD-related documentation has to do with it.

Comment: So the question is why im seing several errors (>30) which are uncorrectable according to SMART parameters description on several drives, yet nothing in system logs indicating that any read from any drive went wrong (system logs should have some entries with I/O errors or timeouts from the controller)

Comment: "*As for Samsung it actually states ...*" -- You're trying to quote something without a citation; that's bogus.  The second link I posted has an accepted answer that links to a Seagate-specific page, with similar definition as the Acronis page, i.e. a rate rather than a count.  "*So the question is why im seing several errors (>30) ...*" -- Now you're bringing up a brand new question/problem?